# Можно ли сделать программу, которая при записку выберет .Net Framework и необходимые блоки кода для правильной работы?

Tags: c#, .net

Например в программе есть 2 блока кода:
 - один для старого .Net Framework,
 - а другой для нового .Net Framework (иными словами его фишки не совместимы со старой версией).

Подскажите, можно ли в зависимости от установленного .Net Framework на машине клиента на ходу выбирать, какой .Net Framework использовать в программе, а так переключать блоки кода?

Comment: _"какой .Net Framework использовать"_ -- в app.config можно указать

Comment: _"есть 2 блока кода: Один для старого .Net Framework, а другой для нового"_ -- у нового есть обратная совместимость со старым.

Comment: Про обратную совместимость я знаю. Вопрос в другом, если я буду писать приложение под старый .Net Framework, то не смогу использовать все фишки нового .Net Framework, хотя они могут быть производительнее, чем изобретение велосипеда на старой версии, а если изначально буду писать под новый, то люди со старым .Net Framework не смогут работать с программой.

Comment: _"если изначально буду писать под новый, то люди со старым"_ -- да, но поставить новый не сложно. или это невозможно по каким-то причинам?

Comment: Ну допустим пользователи XP. Они выше 4,0 поставить не могут. Вы говорили про ""какой .Net Framework использовать" -- в app.config можно указать " А это динамически можно регулировать? Допустим, программу я делал под самую свежую версию, одна особенности последней версии я не использовал и программа может работать на ранних версиях и при запуске выбирается другая версия.

Comment: _"Ну допустим пользователи XP"_ -- а у них сеть есть? можно часть функций приложения вынести в отдельный веб-сервис. _"в app.config можно указать"_ -- да, он транслируется в названиепрограммы.exe.config

Comment: "есть 2 блока кода: Один для старого .Net Framework, а другой для нового" можно в инсталляторе предложить пользователю выбор, какие компоненты ставить исходя из возможностей его системы, но это если сборка большая, для одно-файловой это перебор.

Comment: @rdorn: Мне кажется, имеет смысл оформить это в ответ.

Comment: посмотрите на Microsoft .NET Core  https://dotnet.github.io/ | https://github.com/dotnet/core -- работает на разных платформах.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас большая сборка и уже есть отдельные модули для разных версий .NET, тогда можно в инсталляторе программы предложить пользователю выбор, какие модули устанавливать, исходя из возможностей его системы.

Если сборка одно-файловая, тогда проще собрать несколько вариантов программы под разные версии .NET